# Github certificate not verified in macports

Tags: macos, ssl, github, macports

I am trying to install ros-hydro-genmsg, but encountered the following error.

```
--->  Attempting to fetch 0.4.23-0.tar.gz from https://github.com/ros-gbp/genmsg-release/archive/release/hydro/genmsg/

DEBUG: Fetching distfile failed: SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
```

When I manually go to that link in whatever browser, the file is downloaded immediately. When trying to download it through macports, it does not accept the certificate? I have put both "DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA > SSL" and "GTE CyberTrust Global Root > SSL" to Always trust like suggested elsewhere, but that did not work either.

Comment: Not sure if this is the correct way to go, but I resolved the issue by using the following command: sudo port install ros-hydro-genmsg fetch.ignore_sslcert=yes

Comment: Make sure that you have `curl-ca-bundle` or `certsync` installed. Do you use git from MacPorts or from the Command Line Tools? Those might behave different under these circumstances, because the system one uses certs from the Keychain and the MacPorts one usually doesn't.